# Not quite understand `F(1A) = 1F(A) ∀ A ∈ C1` as the Functor law

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, category-theory

I'm reading this article about Category and Functor in scala: https://hseeberger.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/introduction-to-category-theory-in-scala/

In this part:

> In order to preserve the category structure this mapping must preserve the identity maps and the compositions. More formally:
>
> F(1<sub>A</sub>) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub> ∀ A ∈ C1
>
> F(g ο f) = F(g) ο F(f) ∀ f: A → B, g: B → C where A, B, C ∈ C1

I can't understand well about: F(1<sub>A</sub>) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub>

Why the right part is 1<sub>F(A)</sub> rather than `F(A)`?

I see in other articles, the identity law for Functor is:

```
fa.map(a => a) == fa
```

Which doesn't relate to 1<sub>F(A)</sub>

Comment: `1` seems to be a name for the identity function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confused about what the notation represents.

1<sub>A</sub> represents the identity arrow which is just an arrow/mapping from the object A in the category to itself i.e. A -> A.

Similarly, 1<sub>F(A)</sub> represents the identity functor which is just an arrow from the functor F(A) to itself ie F(A) -> F(A).

Therefore, the arrow 1<sub>F(A)</sub> is not the same as the functor F(A) and so it would be wrong to say that 1<sub>F(A)</sub> = F(A) as you suggest.

To answer your question why F(1<sub>A</sub>) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub>, consider the following in light of the above explanation:

F(1<sub>A</sub>) = F(f : A -> A ) = F(f) : F(A) -> F(A) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub>

Also now that we have cleared up the meaning of the notation, the code snippet is consistent with the functor definition:

```
fa.map(a => a) == fa
```

`fa` is a functor and the map is using the identity function to map every element of the functor to itself. This reproduces a functor which is equivalent to the original functor `fa` and so the map can be represented as 1<sub>F(A)</sub> in the language of category theory.

So you can see there is a concept of an arrow and an object in Category Theory which you must be able to distinguish and understand when looking at the notation. I highly recommend reading the first chapter of [Steve Awodey's Category Theory](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Category-Theory-Oxford-Logic-Guides/dp/0199237182/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1442077884&sr=1-1&keywords=category%20theory) if you are really interested in this subject.

Comment: @IK, thanks, this is my understanding now, is it correct? If `F` is a functor, `F(f: A=>B)` should be `F(A) => F(B)`. If `A`==`B`, the left is `F(A=>A) = F(1<sub>A</sub>)`, and the right is `F(A)=>F(A) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub>,`  so `F(1<sub>A</sub>)==1<sub>F(A)</sub>`

Comment: Let's be clear that there may be many functions (morphisms, in general) from A to A and many functions from F(A) to F(A). But there always is one identity function from A to A and one identity function from F(A) to F(A). Functor F must map the former to the latter. I wrote a [blog post about functors](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/20/functors/), if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

If A is an object in the original category, then F(A) is the corresponding object in the new category. If there is an arrow A->B in the original category, there must be a corresponding arrow F(A)->F(B) in the new category. Since 1<sub>A</sub> is just an arrow A->A, this means there must be an arrow F(A)->F(A) as well, which would be written 1<sub>F(A)</sub>. More compactly, F(1<sub>A</sub>) = 1<sub>F(A)</sub>.